# Could knights navigate a dust storm?

Tags: technology, weather, survival

I'm writing a medieval/post apocalypse world stricken with horrible dust storms that last days or weeks at a time. Would it be possible, using medieval technology, to:

1. protect yourself from such dust storms so you could travel without choking to death, or being buried in sand?
2. navigate in such a storm so you don't get hopelessly lost (assuming you know where you are going when you set out)?

Comment: "Knight" as in "someone wearing armor and riding on a horse even when not in battle"?  Because I don't think that's how knights worked.  Anyway...  if this is their environment, they've developed goggles and filters (like in the book "Dune").  As for navigation, I think most desert dwellers just hunker down and wait for it to pass.

Comment: Medieval or post-apocalyptic? (They're quite different.)

Comment: Knight is just an idecation of the technological level. Most people do hunler down, but raiders try to travle though the storms to strike at unexpecting targets.

Comment: A medevil world that suffered an apocalypse

Comment: There were roads in the medieval (aka Western Europe from the 5th to the 15th century) era.  A better question who be about what Bedouins do during sand storms.

Comment: Echo RonJohn - if you replace 'knight' with 'Bedouin' or 'Mamluk', then you already have a direct comparison to history for your question (they adapted).  Another historical source would be the Mali (most famous under Musa I) and the people of Timbuktu.  They survived and navigated during these times just fine.

Comment: The caked dust on the raiders will immediately identify them to all their neighbors as raiders (nobody legitimate travels during dust!), and they will be promptly sold out for the reward and hanged.

Comment: @Twelfth That could be an answer. Bonus points if you can add some technique these people used to survive desert storms and navigate through deserts.

Comment: Are you aware that the middle ages also happened in dusty places? Check out the crusades for a start - actual knights in the desert. The Arabs were an advanced civilization that dealt with such problems. I'm no expert, but I'm sure you will find a lot about them at the local library - for example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that their only chance to navigate would be a magnetic compass (which is easy to make so long as you actually know about magnetism).

Also, if the storms come from a predictable direction, you might be able to travel down-storm.  Up-storm would probably be pretty difficult.  You can also try to keep the wind on your left or right side but be aware that you would likely be walking a diagonal.

Comment: Consider adding a quick note that compasses must be used carefully in the vicinity of ferrous metals...like that suit of armor, or that big steel sword. An armored knight cannot use a compass without unarmored assistance.

Comment: Don't dust storms also produce quite some static electricity with the friction the collisions of particulates induce which interferes with the earth magnetic field a compass relies on? (Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_storm )